# Applying style on graph objects specifically

Tags: plotting

My goal is to display the data and their mean and +-1 sigma. My code is as below. But the average and +-sigma values ​​are all red dots. Could I get help on how to fix my code to display the +-sigma point(which I have marked as green arrow) as tick(the short vertical bar)?  Epilog or a Directive might be used though..

```
Manipulate[NumberLinePlot[
  {pts[[All, 1]],
   {Mean[pts[[All, 1]]],
    Mean[pts[[All, 1]]] + StandardDeviation[pts[[All, 1]]], 
    Mean[pts[[All, 1]]] - StandardDeviation[pts[[All, 1]]]} },
  PlotRange -> {0, 4}],
 {{pts, Transpose[{RandomReal[{0, 3}, 5], ConstantArray[1, 5]}]}, 
  Locator, Appearance -> None}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) + [`IntervalMarkers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalMarkers.html) + [`IntervalMarkersStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalMarkersStyle.html)

```
Manipulate[
 NumberLinePlot[{
    pts[[All, 1]],
   {Mean @ pts[[All, 1]], 
    Around[Mean[pts[[All, 1]]], StandardDeviation[pts[[All, 1]]]] }},  
  PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
  IntervalMarkers -> "Fences", 
  IntervalMarkersStyle -> <|"FenceStyle" -> Red, "FenceWidth" -> .5|>,
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]], 
{{pts, Transpose[{RandomReal[{0, 3}, 5], ConstantArray[1, 5]}]}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> None}]
```

[image]

Use `IntervalMarkersStyle -> <|"FenceStyle" -> Red, "FenceWidth" -> .5,  "WhiskerStyle" -> Opacity[0]|>` to get

[image]

#### 2. Post-processing:

Style the two points corresponding to mean $\pm$ standarddeviation with two different colors and post-process the output from NumberLinePlot to replace the two markers with `[` and `]`, respectively.

```
replaceWithBrackets = 
  ReplaceAll[{clr : Red | Green, {Point[p_]}} :> 
    Text[Style[clr /. {Red -> "[", Green -> "]"}, 20, Red], p]];

Manipulate[
 replaceWithBrackets @
  NumberLinePlot[{pts[[All, 1]], 
    {Mean[pts[[All, 1]]], 
     Style[Mean[pts[[All, 1]]] - StandardDeviation[pts[[All, 1]]], Red], 
     Style[Mean[pts[[All, 1]]] + StandardDeviation[pts[[All, 1]]],Green]}}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 4}], 
 {{pts, Transpose[{RandomReal[{0, 3}, 5], ConstantArray[1, 5]}]}, 
  Locator, Appearance -> None}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `ListPlot` instead of `NumberLinePlot` gives more flexibility

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[{
   Transpose[{pts[[All, 1]], ConstantArray[1, 5]}],
   {{Mean[pts[[All, 1]]], 2}}, 
   {{Mean[pts[[All, 1]]] + StandardDeviation[pts[[All, 1]]], 2}, 
   {Mean[pts[[All, 1]]] - StandardDeviation[pts[[All, 1]]], 2}}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 3}}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Automatic, {Graphics@{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 4}]}, 
     Scaled[.2]}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 0.2, 
  Axes -> {True, False}], 
  {{pts, Transpose[{RandomReal[{0, 3}, 5], ConstantArray[1, 5]}]}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> None}]
```

[image]

An option using `NumberLinePlot` with `Epilog`

```
Manipulate[
 d = .02;
 NumberLinePlot[{pts[[All, 1]], Mean[pts[[All, 1]]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 4}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, 
    Rectangle[{Mean[pts[[All, 1]]] - StandardDeviation[pts[[All, 1]]] - d, 1.5}, {Mean[pts[[All, 1]]] - StandardDeviation[pts[[All, 1]]] + d, 2.5}], 
    Rectangle[{Mean[pts[[All, 1]]] + StandardDeviation[pts[[All, 1]]] - d, 1.5}, {Mean[pts[[All, 1]]] + StandardDeviation[pts[[All, 1]]] + d, 2.5}]}], 
   {{pts, Transpose[{RandomReal[{0, 3}, 5], ConstantArray[1, 5]}]}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Additional question is...Could I know why the "{" , "}"used twice at {{Mean[pts[[All, 1]]], 2}} ? ( I have tried  {Mean[pts[[All, 1]]], 2} and  found that the it shoud be "{{","}}".. but I  couldn't figure out whyI

Comment: @Soon: The outer braces in `{{Mean[pts[[All, 1]]], 2}}` puts it on the same level as the other items in the list. If you don't, Mathematica thinks it's a one-D list of y values, rather than a list of {x,y} points.